# Refactoring: What is the best architectural approach for organization of classes with import/export csv/xls files from diffrent resources?

Tags: design-patterns, import, architecture, export, refactoring

I have a huge class ImportExportService. It contains methods for import/export to csv/xls files for different data sources and file formats. I'm going to do refactoring.

What is the best architectural approach?

1) I can focus sources

```
Source1Service {export(csv), import(csv)}
Source2Service {export(csv)}
Source3Service {import(xls), export(xls)}
Source4Service {import (xls)}
Source5Service {export(csv)}
```

2) I can focus formats and actions

```
XlsExportService {exportSource3}
XlsImportService {importSource3, importSource4}
CsvExportService {exportSource1, exportSource2, exportSource5}
CsvImportService {importSource1}
```

What do you think which way is better? Maybe you have some other ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: This is really difficult to answer without seeing your existing class. On the surface it would seem that the second option would be preferable as it suggests each class would have a single responsibility as in the SOLID principles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design). If you are not sure, it may be worth trying some small refactoring steps to start with as sometimes a design can suggest itself organically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I've decided to take out methods, which connected with my task, into other class. I hope after that code will be more understandable at least a little=)

Comment: Great. As you refactor, you will start to notice that some methods will use the same member variables. These are good candidates for extracting into a separate class.